# Quantmod: How do I leave the XTS output variable?

Tags: r, quantmod

I am new to R and quantmod. I am trying to get daily data for a user defined ticker symbol, like this:

```
check_symbol<-"GOOG"
check_symbol2<-paste0(check_symbol,".Adjusted")
getSymbols(check_symbol)
temp<-as.vector(GOOG[,check_symbol2])
```

How do I keep `GOOG` as a variable in the `as.vector(GOOG[,check_symbol2])` part of the above code?

Also, any more elegant way of doing this is much appreciated!

Comment: I think you're looking for `get` as in `get(check_symbol)` or `Ad(get(check_symbol))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you'd benefit from using `auto.assign=FALSE` in the call to `getSymbols`:

```
check_symbol <- "GOOG"
check_symbol_data <- getSymbols(check_symbol, auto.assign=FALSE)
temp <- as.vector(Ad(check_symbol_data))
```